# Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, serversocket, server

I really can't work out why this wont work... It seems to work everywhere else I've seen it.

```
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6644);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while(true){
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

}
```

Eclipse keeps telling me 'cannot be resolved' when I hover my mouse over serverSocket on the `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` line. The variable obviously exists and there isn't a typo so what's the matter?

I've already imported `java.io.*` and `java.net.*` so I'm pretty sure I have everything I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `serverSocket` variable is visible only inside the `try` block. Move the declaration outside, maybe like this:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6644);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while(true){
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

}
```